# NGINX Configuration Error using Codex Example: Is This a Typo in Codex?

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I installed NGINX using this tutorial:

[C3M Digital NGINX Tuturial](http://c3mdigital.com/wordpress-performance-server/)

but after reading this article on security issues with "cut and paste" configuration tutorials:

[Neal Poole's article regarding security and NGINX configuration](https://nealpoole.com/blog/2011/04/setting-up-php-fastcgi-and-nginx-dont-trust-the-tutorials-check-your-configuration/)

I decided to follow Poole's suggestion to use the configuration suggested in the WordPress codex:

[Codex on NGINX Configuration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx)

I used the Codex configuration for a multisite installation using W3 Total Cache.  When attempting to start NGINX I get an error saying that the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed.  The error message was:

"Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "//" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/teambrazil.com:18"

When I looked at my site specific configuration at that path I noticed the rewrite rule in the server block was:

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://teambrazil.conf$request_uri redirect;
```

That line in the Codex example was:

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://mysite.conf$request_uri redirect;
```

That looked like a mistake to me, and I changed my line to:

```
rewrite ^ $scheme://teambrazil.com$request_uri redirect;
```

I then attempted to restart NGINX but got the same error message.

My question is: is that a mistake, and is there anything more I have to do aside from restarting NGINX after making this change.

As suggested by both tutorials I set up the directories: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled and /etc/nginx/sites-available and created the appropriate symbolic links using:

```
touch /etc/nginx/sites-available/teambrazil.com
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/teambrazil.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/teambrazil.com
```

Is there something else I need to consider after making this correction?  Or was it not an error in the first place?  I'm pretty stuck here.

BTW, I am using Debian squeeze as an OS on Amerinoc's VPS.  I'm just getting familiar with VPS administration and am pretty much a noob.

Thanks very much, would appreciate any input.

Comment: At a glance (and just a guess at the moment) - I would say it is the problem of copy and paste you mention. There are two lines in the per site configuration section that start with "//": // Additional rules go here. and // Only include one of the files below. They are intended to be replaced and so need to be removed. Nginx uses '#' as the comment sign, so // is not valid. If that isn't the issue, post your full configuration and hopefully you can get a few more suggestions.

Comment: Cyberx86, thank you!  I had no idea, assumed, like PHP the "//"s were valid for single line comments.  I made the changes and ended up with a 502 bad gateway error.  But at least NGINX restarted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wordpress Codex includes two lines in the [Per Site Configuration](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#Per_Site_configuration) section that start with "`//`":

- `// Additional rules go here`
- `// Only include one of the files below`

Both of these lines are meant as placeholders, and need to be removed and replaced with appropriate configurations.

Nginx uses '`#`' as the comment sign, so '`//`' is not valid. In general, you will find that 'directives' start a line - therefore the error '`unknown directive "//"`' suggests that there is a line starting with '`//`' which Nginx is trying to interpret as a directive (and since it isn't a valid directive, Nginx throws an error).